# New tab selenium + js

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing

Good day, i want to open new tests ('it' method) in new tabs, now using this approach:

`driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();`

```
beforeEach(() => {
    // driver.manage().window().open('url');    !doesn't works!
});

afterEach(async() => {
//    something like driver quit etc.   });


it('something', async () => { ... });
```

Thanks for help and review.

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeEach(() => {
driver.executeScript("window.open('your url', '_blank')");
});
```

!make sure to wrap the method in quotation marks ("")!

executeScript "Executes a snippet of JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window."
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_IWebDriver.html#execute

_blank - URL is loaded into a new window, or tab. This is default
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp